# How to use OpenDistro for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use OpenDistro for authentication on AWS:
    https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/api/

tried:

```
https://1.2.3.4.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_opendistro/_security/api/internalusers/
```

but getting:

```
{
    "error": "no handler found for uri [/_opendistro/_security/api/internalusers/] and method [GET]"
}
```

What is the proper URL/test just to see users or basic authentication?

Answer (score 0):

From the URL, it looks as though you are using Amazon Elasticsearch Service. Open Distro for Elasticsearch is an open source project with distributions of Elasticsearch OSS, and plugins. You must deploy and run Open Distro yourself.

See our main page here: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/

You can also have a look at this post for a simple way to run Open Distro: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/blog/open%20distro%20for%20elasticsearch%20updates/2019/03/Get-Up-and-Running-with-Open-Distro-for-Elasticsearch/